# Access VBA: AutoExec macro can't find function?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, startup

I'm trying to execute a function that opens forms at startup and I created the `AutoExec` macro.

I have a module called `startup` in which there is a function called `startup`.

The `AutoExec` macro has the action `Run Code` with a function named `startup ()`.

When I start my database, I get the error, "The expression you entered has a function that Access can't find".

Is there something I'm doing wrong? 
Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: nevermind...figured it out. For anyone interested: the function name cant be the same as the module name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the function name the same as the module name. 
Change the function name from `startup()` to `onStart()`.